# What hardware does SLS actually share with STS?

Tags: sls, manufacturing, shuttle-derived

I was thinking about it for a while and realized I really don't know. I'm guessing it's:

- The RS-25s
- The SRB segments
- SRB seals/joints
- SRB nosecone assemblies +(avionics/separation motors/housings)?
- SRB decouplers?
- SRB ground support/pad mounts?
- Engine controllers?
- Tank pressurization systems?

What else? I know the main tank's been almost completely rebuilt from the ground up. I'm sure the avionics are completely new. I'm guessing the SRBs are completely the same (for now). Orion & the second (third?) stage are all new (at least to STS hardware).

How much of this legacy system is actually legacy?

Note: I don't mean previously-flown hardware, just hardware which is "rolling" off the same production "lines". At some point the question breaks down if everything's hand-built and a decade's passed since components have been put together.

Answer (score 8):

Partial answer

- The SSMEs / RS-25 are mostly reused but some parts have been redesigned.  (Since SLS expends the RS-25s, in the unlikely case that it flies a lot, they plan to gradually improve new engines they build.)  Two are leftovers from the shuttle program that never flew.
  [image]

https://www.nasa.gov/centers/stennis/news/releases/2021/NASA-Fires-Up-Artemis-RS-25-Rocket-Engines-with-New-Components

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20170008958/downloads/20170008958.pdf

[image]

Image source [Where are the lost RS-25D Block 2 engines?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/40792/where-are-the-lost-rs-25d-block-2-engines/40793#40793)  Note: "30 years of flawless performance" is not true. 5 pad aborts, one in-flight shutdown, a myriad of smaller problems.

- Some of the SRB segments are reused, some are or will be new. (Since SLS expends the SRBs, in the unlikely case that it flies a lot, eventually they will have to make new segments.) It does not say specifically, but I do not think they made any changes to the seals / joints.

[image]

Image source Northrop-Grumman, sadly I lost the link.

- The engine controllers are new.

https://www.rocket.com/article/rs-25-main-engine-controllers-tested-sls-debut

- The SRB forward skirt is legacy hardware with some additional insulation added.

[image]

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20180001125/downloads/20180001125.pdf

- The booster separation motors are legacy designs.

https://www.northropgrumman.com/wp-content/uploads/SLS-Motors.pdf

This slide summarizes the situation with the boosters:

[image]

https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2021/07/srbs-from-shuttle-to-sls/

The Thrust Vector Control System is basically identical to the STS version.

[Are the APUs on the SLS SRBs planned to be hydrazine powered?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36858/are-the-apus-on-the-sls-srbs-planned-to-be-hydrazine-powered/43614#43614)

Comment: Is it weird that I want to tell someone to install 2062 and 2063 in opposite positions, rather than adjacent?

Comment: @RussellBorogove depends on whether SLS can make it to any orbit on just 2 engines, regardless of where they are in the cluster I guess - if not, its an automatic abort anyway, surely?

Comment: Forget failure, if for some reason these new engines perform better/worse you will have asymmetric thrust. Computers can probably correct for this, but if you can avoid problems why not?

Answer (score 1):

> Orion & the second (third?) stage are all new (at least to STS hardware).

Orion's service module, the [European Service Module](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Service_Module) supplied by the [European Space Agency (ESA)](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Space_Agency) and built by [Airbus Defence and Space](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_Defence_and_Space) based on the design of the [Automated Transfer Vehicle (ATV)](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_Transfer_Vehicle) uses a [Space Shuttle Orbital Maneuvering System (OMS)](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Orbital_Maneuvering_System) engine ([Aerojet Rocketdyne](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerojet_Rocketdyne)'s [AJ10-190](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/AJ-10)) for its main propulsion system.